# Where should I place water treatment plants in Simcity 4?

Tags: simcity-4

I have an industrial city that needs several water treatment plants due to the high amount of water pollution it produces. I've never been quite sure what the best placement for water treatment plants, or their exact workings is.

Should they be placed:

- Anywhere? (if they just affect the entire cities water supply)
- Near the source of the pollution? (if they stop its production)
- Or near the water source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 90% sure that the correct answer is anywhere, however, keep in mind they have a rather significant NIMBY issue, so keep them away from sensitive zones.

Answer (score 2):

I've always found that slapping them down in industrial zones helps to alleviate the NIMBY issues they generate. That and by any rivers or seas seems to work decently (I dont' play landlocked maps due to the desire for street variety/love of bridges)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't bother with treatment facilities in an industrial city at all, I usually simply import all the water I need from another city. This is cheaper as it does not require a treatment facility, and also allows a neighbouring city to run a profit of the sale of their water.